# Symfony: embedding collection of forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to embed collection of forms into one based on this cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

I have following database shcema: product ---< POS shortcut >--- POS item

in controller i'm initiatig form like this:

```
$pos = new PosList();
for ($i=0;$i<10 ;$i++ ) {
    $scut1 = new PosShortcut();
    $pos->addPosShortcut($scut1);
}
$form = $this->createForm(new PosListType(), $pos);
```

Then i have form for POSShortcut:

```
$builder
    ->add('posList','hidden')
    ->add('product','entity',array(
        'required'=>false,
        'empty_value'=>'Choose product...',
        'label'=>'Shordcut product',
        'class'=>'StockBundle:Product',
        'property'=>'name'
));
```

And of course main form, what includes PosShortcut form:

```
<...>
    ->add('posShortcut','collection',array('type'=>new PosShortcutType()))
<...>
```

Now the problem is that for a POS shortcut item, POSList id is set to NULL when it's written in database. Reason is very simple, i haven't set PosList value for new shortcut when i'm creating them in controller at firstplace. But the issue is that i can not do that in this state, because POS item does not exists in database yet.

How to get over this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PosList
{
    public function addPosShortcut($shortcut)
    {
        $this->shortcuts->add($shortcut);
        $shortcut->setPosList($this);  // *** This will link the objects ***
    }
```

Doctrine 2 will take care of the rest.  You should be aware that all 10 of your shortcuts will always be posted.